# The meaning of "have someone up to do"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms, idiomatic-language

I heard this in a [movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean%27s_Thirteen):

> The kids are grateful. They're gonna **have you up to visit** next month.

Is **have somebody up to do something** idiomatic?

Comment: I can't hear it now, but: to have someone up means to have them visit, a place that is either high  up, like up a mountain, OR someone from a state that is to the south of where the speakers are. For example, if you live in Minnesota, you might say: I have guests [who have come] up from the South. So: They're gonna have you [come ] up to visit next month. Another: Our friends were up [had come up] from Paris or Moscow or New York. It means: you are to the north of the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will have you

in ...  for example, to meet with us (interview, sales pitch, whatever)

out ...  out to where we are, for a visit / meeting / interview /presentation

up ...   up to where we are (in a high-rise building, or to a place north of you) for a visit

over ...  to where we are, perhaps for dinner or drinks / entertainment of some kind

down ... to where we are, perhaps to a beach-house, for a weekend stay